# CakePdf plugin wkhtmltopdf binary is not found

Tags: cakephp, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to implement this plugin https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf

In my view methods I have add this code

```
   public function view($id = null) {
       $this->User->id = $id;
        $this->autoRander="false";
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
          $this->pdfConfig = array(
                'orientation' => 'portrait',
                'filename' => 'User_' . $id
            );

        $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
    }
```

I also add

```
 Configure::write('CakePdf', array(
        'engine' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf',
        'options' => array(
            'print-media-type' => false,
            'outline' => true,
            'dpi' => 96
        ),
        'margin' => array(
            'bottom' => 15,
            'left' => 50,
            'right' => 30,
            'top' => 45
        ),
        'orientation' => 'landscape',
        'download' => true
    ));
```

Now problem is when I am trying to execute this code that have given me this error **wkhtmltopdf binary is not found or not executable: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf** I have install wkhtmltopdf. Here in CakePdf plugin code they have used

```
protected $binary = '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf';
```

How can I used this engine to solve it?How can I determine this path ?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. On my Mac, the correct path is `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`.
To override the default path, I added a row in `Configure::write` block:

```
Configure::write('CakePdf', array(
    'binary' => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf', // set the correct path here
    'engine' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf',
    'options' => array(
        'print-media-type' => false,
        'outline' => true,
        'dpi' => 96
    ),
    'margin' => array(
        'bottom' => 15,
        'left' => 50,
        'right' => 30,
        'top' => 45
    ),
    'orientation' => 'landscape',
    'download' => true
));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MAMP change

```
// app/Plugin/CakePdf/Pdf/Engine/WkHtmlToPdfEngine.php
protected $binary = '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf';
```

to

```
// app/Plugin/CakePdf/Pdf/Engine/WkHtmlToPdfEngine.php 
protected $binary = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf';
```

Answer (score 0):

`whereis wkhtmltopdf` in command shell.

Comment: "I have install wkhtmltopdf.", "How can I determine this path". This tells me he has installed wkhtmltopdf but it's not at the location the code expects and he wants to determine the path to the binary. If that's the case my answer is correct. If I am misunderstanding I'll let the author tell me otherwise.

Comment: @Alimon Karim Btw this statement `$this->autoRander="false";` won't do anything. The property name is `autoRender` and it's value needs to be boolean not string.

Comment: I have problem on engine.I need help help for WkHtmlToPdf.I have install it but it is not working. Do it work in live server?